# Is it OK to get online help and then answer?

Tags: support, plagiarism

I answered a question with the help of another site, but a user flagged my answer, and down-voted me. Is this wrong?

Comment: Based on the other answers you have... it's certainly possible the downote was for other reasons from a separate user. but plagiarism is never ok

Comment: You have to be a little more specific with your question. What exactly do you mean by "with the help of another website" ? Did you copy and paste content from that site or did you just learn something on there that you then used to write the answer all by yourself? Also, please keep in mind that voting on a post can never be *wrong*. People can down/upvote posts for any reason they want to. Asking whether your answer is good or not is a different question (and one nobody can currently answer without more information)

Comment: You should cite your sources if you're answering based on information on another site. Also use quotation formatting if you're copy/pasting content from somewhere else.

Comment: Googling a question's title and pasting the first hit in an answer is not the kind of answer we're looking for.

Answer (score 22):

What [your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640122) did was [plagiarize information from other websites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45596421). In other words, **you just copied-and-pasted it**, stealing someone else's work and claiming credit for it as if it were your own. You didn't link to the original source, you didn't give the author's name, and you didn't format the text as a quotation.

This is totally unacceptable on Stack Overflow. We have [specific guidelines for how to reference external resources](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

When you fail to adhere to those guidelines, your answer is subject to being downvoted and deleted.

And while you *may* quote excerpts from external resources if you attribute them properly, we *prefer* that posts be your own *original* work that adds value to the site, rather than consisting primarily of text copied from somewhere else. In most cases, you do not have legal permission to copy someone else's content.

As [CodeCaster advised in a comment on this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354913/is-it-okay-to-get-online-help-and-then-answer#comment503393_354913):

> Googling a question's title and pasting the first hit in an answer is not the kind of answer we're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

> I answered a question with the help of another website ...

You can do that, but you should:

1. Replicate the other website's relevant stuff as a cite:

   > At web-site XY it says:
   >
   > > Lorem ipsum ...
2. Link to that website and make it clear it's not your work (or otherwise, if it is)